# Why does my program terminate after the while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop

The following program is supposed to ask the user how many students he wants to grade then have the user input the grades and get the average.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct person {
    char Name[100];
    int ID;
    int Age;
    double Score;
};

int main(void) {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    int size;

    printf("How many students are you grading?(Not more than 100)-->");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    struct person *student;

    double total=0,i=0, average;

    student= malloc(sizeof(struct person));

    //struct person student;
    printf("Enter the following information:\n");

    while (i<size) {
        printf("%lf\n%lf\n",total,i);
        printf("\n");

        printf("Name:");
        scanf("%s",student->Name);

        printf("ID:");
        scanf("%d",&student->ID);

        printf("Age:");
        scanf("%d",&student->Age);

        printf("Score:");
        scanf("%lf",&student->Score);

        total = total + student->Score;

        i++;
    }
```

The code works fine until it needs to print out the average based on user input, at which point the program terminates without giving the average nor an error message.

```
    if(size==1){
        average = total / size;
        printf("Class average is %0.2lf\n", average);
    }
        else
        {
            average=total/i;
        printf("Class average is %0.2lf\n", average);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KbcdcCXqsgzdraFj). Please make sure that you are compiling and running your latest intended code and please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What environment are you using? It may be printing the result and exiting right after that. Try running your code from Command Prompt or terminal software.

Answer (score 2):

Most console programs are intended to be run from some kind of console host like windows cmd, where the output stays there and it would be annoying for user to do some additional work to end the program so they can run another command, but since you are just testing it, you should put some code at the end to wait for some user input, now there are many ways to do that like: getch(), getchar(), scanf("%*c"), system("pause") so you can try those, but some compilers do this automatically in debug mode, sometimes you just need to specify the behaviour in your IDE settings.

Comment: you were right. The funny thing is I already have a habit  of using system("pause") with code::blocks, but some reason it didn't occur to me that that was the issue here. I need to pay more attention.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is that the console is closing before you can read the average.

You could add:

getchar();

Before you return 0; in int main.

Comment: That may not suffice. After the last.`scanf("%lf",....)` a newline character may remain in the input stream's buffer, and then `getchar()` may consume it and return immediately.